# HTMl Agility pack, tlk.io

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I tried to read the messages from the chat website https://tlk.io/, where you can choose a random channel and enter the conversation.
And now I want to extract the written messages via HTML Agility in C#.
So the xpath for the messages for example: /html/body/div/section/dl[19]/dd[3].
So i tried to search in div for all messages
Here is my code for the channel 123:

```
    var url = "https://tlk.io/123";

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

    var HtmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

    var Messages = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
        .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
        .Equals("chat")).ToList();
```

The problem now is that I can´t find the messages in the given xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages aren't in the html retrieved because they're loaded dynamically after the initial html is loaded.

I don't know anything about tlk.io, but behind the scenes it seems to have some API that is queried that returns a JSON message containing the chat messages (for what they're worth...). So, you could tap into that instead to get the information. For example;

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    var html = webClient.DownloadString("https://tlk.io/123");
    Match chatIdFinder = new Regex(@"Talkio\.Variables\.chat_id = '(?<chatid>\d+)'").Match(html);
    if (!chatIdFinder.Success) throw new ArgumentException("Could not find chat id");
    var chatId = chatIdFinder.Groups["chatid"].Value;
    var json = webClient.DownloadString($"https://tlk.io/api/chats/{chatId}/messages");

    JArray messages = JArray.Parse(json);
    var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    foreach (dynamic message in messages)
    {
        JToken chatMessage = message.body;
        JToken nickname = message.nickname;
        JToken timestamp = message.timestamp;
        var messageTime = epoch.AddSeconds(timestamp.Value<int>()).ToLocalTime();
        Console.WriteLine($"{messageTime}: {nickname.Value<string>()}: {chatMessage.Value<string>()}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer!
Very easy to understand.